# Which monospaced "slab serif" fonts can be recommended for use as web-font?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

For a website project, I need to find a good looking web-font that fits the following parameters:

1. it must be a "slab serif"
2. it must be "monospace"

Keeping my question short and simple: Which monospaced "slab serif" fonts can be recommended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A search yielded a [list of possible alternatives](http://www.fontshop.com/fontlist/genres/monospaced_slab_serif/), top of which is **Courier**.

While it may be ubiquitous and not particularly interesting, it's a native font on every [? almost every] OS and present on most systems. Thus it will be rendered well without additional work on your part.

The other fonts listed there which satisfy the requirement for slab serifs are, along with a number of overtly "typewriter" fonts, [MVB Fantabular](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/mvb_fonts/mvb_fantabular_ot/ot_ps), [Blackbox Mono Serif](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/psyops_type_foundry/blackbox_mono_serif_subset_ot/ot_ps) and [Lucida Typewriter Serif](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/creative_alliance/lucida_typewriter_serif_std_regular/ot_ps). Any of them are likely to work as web fonts.

Google Web Fonts includes **Cutive Mono** which is very similar to Courier.

Comment: worth noting that if you use google web font, you can use any of the monospaced slab serif fonts included in google (there's loads of them) and you don't need to worry about whether people have them installed or not.

Comment: and it's free!!!

Answer (score 0):

LUXI Mono ? Supposedly an open source alternative to Lucida Typewriter (serif)

Comment: Is that an answer or a question? Please explain better what you mean! Welcome!

Comment: Hi ramesh, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your input. As Kurt says, please clarify whether this is a suggestion. If it is, please include a screenshot of your suggested font and a link to a place where it can be legally obtained. You can [edit] your post with that info by clicking the [edit] button or this [edit] link. If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing an enjoy the site!